# Magento connect manager not working

Tags: magento

I'm working with magento 1.9.2.4 on my local computer, I'm using XAMPP.

Everything is running fine on the front end and on the backend, the only problem that I'm having is that when I'm using magento connect manager (mysite.com/downloader) the url is not working properly.

I'm able to access the downloader but when I try to do something the url just loops, like this **mysite.com/downloader/?A=settings** and if I click something again the url will be like this **mysite.com/downloader/?A=settings?A=settings** and take me back to home.

It just loops and keep adding the click to the url and never refreshing the page.
I did some changes on the htaccess and nothing seem to be working.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Have you check magento log file for error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using local environment then try by removing htaccess file from downloader folder.

OR

edit htaccess file from downloader
Add following code

```
# Disable access to downloader
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow From All
```